# How to show property of masterpage on a page in Umbraco

Tags: templates, inheritance, umbraco, master-pages

I have an umbraco project with a masterpage (with it's own content type) and a homepage underneath it.

The masterpage content type includes stuff like the footer, header etc.

However when I look at the homepage, the properties of the masterpage don't display.
In the masterpage template I have the line:

```
<umbraco:Item field="footerText" runat="server" />
```

But this doesn't pull the footerText property from the masterpage properties.

I am guessing it has something to do with the fact that properties are not inherited, so how do we go around that? Writing a simple macro that pulls the data or is there a quicker way?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to access fields belonging to a parent node, you would set the recursive attribute to true:

```
<umbraco:Item field="footerText" recursive="true" runat="server" />
```

When you are editing your masterpages via the template editor in the Umbraco backend, you can use the "Insert umbraco page field" dialog to help build your  tags.

Comment: @Douglas Ludlow, Hi i am using macro: <umbraco:Macro ID="Macro5" recursive="true" LatestProjectdetails="[#projectSection]" Alias="Latest-Project" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>. here projectSection is my property and i want to pass this property from parent so that i have used a keyword called recursive but it's not working with the macro while it's working with <umbraco:Item field="projectSection" recursive="true" runat="server" />. can you suggest me on this plz.